# What geographical database does Facebook use?

Tags: facebook, api, google-maps, geocoding, geonames

I'm working on an auto-complete input field somewhat similar to the one on Facebook where you start typing a city and suggestions appear.

I have been testing Geonames but it's not as precise as Facebook.. and Google's geocoding API can be used only with a map which I don't need.

Does anyone know what web service Facebook uses for geocoding? Or does it have its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook uses "Location Pages" or "Places pages", which are created by people, businesses and everybody else on facebook. When you type in a facebook city/location textbox, it will search its pages with that name.

Sample of page it shows in City/Location textbox typeahead:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Makati/102152049827030

It's not actually a database of Places and Locations or whatever geo-system. It is community-centered, meaning all possible places / street / commercial establishment one can go to.

Comment: I did not assume that. They must have accustomed a lot of locations for it to be so precise. Thanks!